# R Displaying groups in a dot chart

Tags: r, graphics

I've made some researches on how to display graph using R, but I really don't find any answer to my problem.

I have this matrix representing cars and a vector representing the relation between groups and the different points (individuals) of this matrix. Let's say:

```
cars # 2d dimension matrix
categories # vector of correspondance between cars and group
```

The value at index [i] of the "categories" vector represent the category number (of the i em car in the matrix).

What i do want to do, is display a graph (dotchart) which display all these cars sorted by colors corresponding to their actual category.

Let's say we have 5 categories and these 5 colors :

```
colors <- c("white","gray","yellow","orange","red")
```

Is there any one who can help me out ?
Thanks!

Comment: If you post some sample data that would be helpful in answering.  You can use dput to give a taste.

Comment: Did you mean to write scatterplot when you wrote "dot chart"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your cars variable has two columns (say, an X and a Y), and that you want to plot their relationship.

In that case, this is simple if you use the [plot](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/plot.html) function:

```
plot(cars, col=colors[categories])
```

For example, you could generate and plot some random data like this:

```
cars = matrix(runif(2000), ncol=2) # 2d dimension matrix
categories = sample(1:5, 1000, replace=TRUE) # vector of correspondance between cars and group
colors = c("white","gray","yellow","orange","red")

plot(cars, col=colors[categories])
```

Answer (score 0):

do you mean something like this?

```
 require(ggplot2)
 p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) 
 p + geom_point(aes(colour = cyl)) + scale_colour_gradient(low = "blue")
```

this is from ggplot [help pages](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/geom_point.html): [image]

Comment: Yep this is also what i ment! Thanks :D

Comment: @hahahaha If you want to ensure that each value of cyl is assigned its own color, you'll want to use `aes(colour = factor(cyl))`.